# Center a string on a line of a specific number of characters

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii, string-formatting

I need a little bit of advice on a project I'm working on.

I am creating an ascii ticket that bases its content on what you input into a scanner. Each line should contain 51 characters between borders and include the event , date/time, and location. The event gets its own line and the date/time and location share a line. 
Heres what it ought to look like

> |_________________YOUR EVENT HERE___________________|
>
> |DATE AND TIME___________________EVENT LOCATION HERE|

The underscores are just there to show you how much space is between border and string, it does not actually show up in the program.

I understand you should use a for loop to determine how many spaces go before and after your string, but i'm lost as to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your line is 51 characters. Let's call this `lineLength`.
The string that you want to center also has a length, let's call that `stringLength`.

The number of spaces that you must add to the string that you want to center to make it fill up the entire line is: `lineLength - stringLength`. Half of these spaces should go before your string and half of these should go after your string.

However, what if you string is say 48 characters long? Then the different is `3` which doesn't nicely divide by two. So you take half of `lineLength - stringLength` (rounded down) and add that number of spaces in front, and then the remainder you add behind the string that you want to center.

This should help you a bit. Since you know how to use a for-loop I left two "TODO" placeholders in that you need to replace with a for-loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringToCenter = "blablah";
    int lineLength = 51;
    int stringLength = stringToCenter.length();

    int missingSpaces = lineLength - stringLength;
    int paddingBefore = missingSpaces / 2;
    int paddingAfter = missingSpaces - paddingBefore;

    // TODO: write code to print "paddingBefore" spaces

    System.out.print(stringToCenter);

    // TODO: write code to print "paddingAfter" spaces

}
```